# Book series about a magic family with magic parents and kids having adventures learning magic

Tags: story-identification, books, magic

Looking for a middle-grade fantasy book series (possibly three or four) about a magic family. Think there was a brother and 2 sisters. One sister was younger than the other two. Maybe there were 4 kids? The parents were magic as well but the kids got into adventures learning their magic.

First book in the series has a dragon hiding his treasure and had the word "Wyvern" in the title possibly? Late 80s early 90s I think.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  How many books were there?  Do you recall the covers of any of them?  What age level were these books?

Comment: At least three-four. I think the first book had Wyvern or another spelling of dragon in the title. I would say middle grade.

Comment: @Brian - That narrows it down considerably, but I can't see any titles with a description that matches your; https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/se.cgi?arg=wyvern&type=Fiction+Titles

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.